# How to calculate the AUC from a ROC plot without the underlying data?

Tags: r, roc, auc

I am doing a meta-analysis on the performance of certain risk assessment instruments. My goal is to pool the AUC estimates of several validity studies for a particular instrument. However, I came across a few studies that do not provide the AUC estimate itself, but rather only present the ROC curve.
In such cases I have used https://apps.automeris.io/wpd/ to get the values corresponding to each data point. **However, the problem is that even though I have the values for sensitivity and 1-specificity and can use R to plot the ROC curve myself, I don't know which function to use in order to calculate the Area Under the Curve (AUC).** This is due to the fact that all R packages/functions that allow me to calculate the AUC use the underlying data as input. That is, the predictor and the response rather than the values for sensitivity and 1-specificity.

I have read the documentation for the 'pROC' package in R, but did not find anything helpful. 
I guess I could just integrate the area under the curve of plot using *integrate()*? The problem with that is, however, that I would not receive the confidence intervals for the AUC (which I need in my meta-analysis).

Here is the data that I generated from one of the ROC-curves (by using https://apps.automeris.io/wpd/):

```
# data table:
AUC_data_1 <- tibble("1-specificity" = c(-0.0031751800795011,
0.05421559172249585, 0.12174003874893036,0.20579144833428253,
0.3012443157265138, 0.502266554865223, 0.6205366469297053,
0.8417661384716209, 
sensitivity = c(0.002260831241825745, 0.16879823941344285,
0.45899739288954267, 0.5804040305755962, 0.7849062327396981,
0.8634686874873007, 0.9710785309748188, 0.9977448923815709))

# roc curve generated from data:
plot(AUC_data_1)
```

I would like to calculate the AUC from this ROC-curve. However, since I don't have the underlying data (i.e., response and predictor), I can't use the pROC package in R.

Comment: This doesn't really look like a ROC curve. The first 1-specificity value is negative, and it is not anchored at (0, 0) and (1,1).

Comment: You are right. The numbers are just approximations as they are extracted directly from the graph itself. I should have cleaned them up first before posting them. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is cleanup your data. A ROC curve starts at (0, 0) and ends at (1, 1). If these points are missing from your curve, the AUC will be underestimated. Here is an attempted fix:

```
AUC_data_1 <- tibble("one.minus.specificity" = c(0,
0.05421559172249585, 0.12174003874893036,0.20579144833428253,
0.3012443157265138, 0.502266554865223, 0.6205366469297053,
0.8417661384716209, 1),
sensitivity = c(0, 0.16879823941344285,
0.45899739288954267, 0.5804040305755962, 0.7849062327396981,
0.8634686874873007, 0.9710785309748188, 0.9977448923815709, 1))
```

Make sure you understand the quality and reliability of the data you get from this service.

Then as you guesses it's just an integration game. I like the [trapz](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/topics/trapz) function from pracma which uses the trapezoidal rule:

```
library(pracma)
trapz(AUC_data_1$one.minus.specificity, AUC_data_1$sensitivity)
[1] 0.6268943
```

Regarding uncertainties, you should have a look at the work by Obuchowski (1) that expresses the variance of the ROC curve as a function of the AUC, sample size and parameters of the binormal fit that you can obtain with the sensitivity and specificity only:

```
 model <- lm(1-one.minus.specificity~sensitivity, AUC_data_1)
```

You will [find the code directly in the pROC source](https://github.com/xrobin/pROC/blob/master/R/obuchowski.R). Although it is private and you should use it at your own risk (the functions are not exported and might disappear at any time). Something like this:

```
A <- coefficients(model)[1]
B <- coefficients(model)[2]
kappa <- n.controls / n.cases # number of case and control observations
# use internal function at your own risk
pROC:::var.params.obuchowski(A, B, kappa) / n.cases
[1] 0.1125403
```

They also propose an approach that doesn't need the binormal coefficients:

```
A <- qnorm(theta) * 1.414
(0.0099 * exp(-A^2/2)) * ((5 * A^2 + 8) + (A^2 + 8)/kappa) / n.cases
[1] 0.7846169
```

Where theta is the AUC of the curve you calculated above.

1. Nancy A. Obuchowski, Donna K. McClish (1997). ``Sample size determination for diagnostic accurary studies involving binormal ROC curve indices''. Statistics in Medicine, 16(13), 1529--1542. DOI: [(SICI)1097-0258(19970715)16:13<1529::AID-SIM565>3.0.CO;2-H](https://dx.doi.org/(SICI)1097-0258(19970715)16:13%3C1529::AID-SIM565%3E3.0.CO;2-H).
2. Nancy A. Obuchowski, Micharl L. Lieber and Frank H. Wians Jr. (2004) “ROC Curves in Clinical Chemistry: Uses, Misuses, and Possible Solutions”. Clinical Chemistry, 50, 1118–1125. DOI: [10.1373/clinchem.2004.031823](http://dx.doi.org/10.1373/clinchem.2004.031823).

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful and solves my problem. And sorry for posting the data before cleaning it up first.